# How do I save a class from another class aka generating/compiling/building

Tags: java, build

Okay so lets rewrite this.
I am making a program.
I have a class 1 and a class 2.
Class 1 includes strings with download links and such.
Class 2 includes the actual program that generates it, with the fields the GUI and everything.

You can start the program, fill some fields with information such as download link, file name etc.

So, when you fill the fields, you can press a button, when you press this button, it will generate a java file filled with all the the code from class 1.

Class 1 includes a bunch of strings for example:

```
String test = field1fromclass2;
```

So basicially, class 1 is done and the code is working, but what I want is some kind of method or way to save class 1 to a custom directory.
How would I do this?

Comment: You want to create a new java class and compile it from a method in some other class?

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question. If you want to be taken seriously, replace "etc blablabla" with whatever it's supposed to mean.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to look at the reflection APIs. This allows you to create objects from a "template" on the fly. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/